# Jacoco, SonarQube and microservices, how to set relative path?

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm trying to set test coverage in sonarqube using jacoco, paths to execs are set as /target/jacoco.exec, how to set them relative paths? Example path to exec in my project is

```
CRU/BackOffice/microserviceName/target/jacoco.exec
```

SonarCube gives me 0% coverage, and I think it's becouse of the paths.

Edit:

I've tried absolute path, still nothing.

logs about the coverage:

```
2017.08.04 08:36:47 DEBUG ce[AV2r9ZLRJhl0ZEsm2J2c][o.s.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute new coverage | time=6635ms
2017.08.04 08:36:47 DEBUG ce[AV2r9ZLRJhl0ZEsm2J2c][o.s.s.c.t.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute coverage measures | time=104ms
```

sonarqube version is 6.4.

Comment: Please verify, that you have coverage >0%, when using an absolute path.

Comment: You should also have a look at the (detailed) SonarQube log. Also update your question adding the version number(s).